# Android emoticons (SMILEY ICONS)

Tags: android, emoticons

I am develoing and application and people can chat using it.
I want to use smileys (I mean smiley icons, images ).
Has android sdk its own smiley icon set?
and if yes how can I implement it to the keyboard?
I searched but could not find.
I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use default R.drawable icons in which are included in SDK.
smile icons are also included.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable.html

And you can find them your own sdk-tool directory 
android-sdk-directory/platforms/android-7/data/res/drawable-hdpi

You can create your original IME keyboards.
reference is here.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html

Comment: when I create the keyboars like you tell, the users will pick Images to add smiles??? and you have sample code?